# Norms, Inner Products, Orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that $(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + · · · + \alpha_n)^2 ≤ n \cdot (\alpha^2_1 + \alpha^2_2 + · · · + \alpha^2_n)$  for $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: Cauchy–Bunyakovskii–Schwarz (CBS) Inequality is one of the titles before the question. Not sure how to answer, feel very lost on this topic. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As Lord Shark said in the comment, this is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, namely:

$\sum a_i^2\sum b_i^2\geq (\sum a_ib_i)^2$ for $a_i,b_i \geq 0$

You can take all the $b_i$'s to equal $1$ to prove this particular result.

For the general case, there are numerous way to prove it. For example, try to use induction on the number of $a_i$'s (or $b_i$'s) by first showing that it holds for (in your case) $n=2$ and then using this basis case in your inductive step or have a look here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: Thank you for help, its appreciated.